# Not able to load my custom java classes in JRuby

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, jruby-java-interop

I have created one java project. Folder structure is like

```
Test
  - src
      -TestJavaCall.java
```

I created jar of this prject test.jar.

Code in my ruby file is as follows.

```
include Java
require '/home/office/test.jar'
java_import Java::TestJavaCall

 testJava = TestJavaCall.new
```

When i am executing this script, i am getting this error.

```
NameError: cannot link Java class TestJavaCall
  get_top_level_proxy_or_package at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:49
                   const_missing at file:/home/spaul/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/java/java_module.rb:4
```

Please let me know what is the way to use custom java classes in ruby?

Source code of TestJavaCall.java

```
public class TestJavaCall {

    public void testJavaCall()
    {
        System.out.println("test java call");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the source code for `TestJavaCall`.

Comment: @chrylis I have posted the source code the TestJavaCall

Comment: Does this work if you add `/home/office/test.jar` to the CLASSPATH environment variable for the JRuby launch?

Comment: Also, instead of using `java_import`, try just `import TestJavaCall`.

Comment: @chrylis I tried to set CLASSPATH to JRuby run configuration and also used import, but still getting linkage error. :-(